# React Hot Module Replacement On Windows 10 / Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, express, webpack, windows-10

So I've been trying to configure hot reload for React, I'm using webpack2 with express and webpack-hot-middleware for the HMR.

I run the server from ubuntu using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, and I use normal Chrome on Windows for the client.

It works just fine on my mac, however on Windows it doesn't, I tried connecting the browser to 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1', also explicitly setting the hostname on express to 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' and '0.0.0.0' but none of them work.

Also Webpack doesn't even rebuilds on file changes.

#### This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.jsx'),
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['react', 'env']
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Middleware configuration

```
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ', port);
});
```

Comment: Aren't there any error logs in console?

Comment: No, no error logs,  just  the 'hmr connected' message, but that's the only log

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this as well and it seemed to be a problem with file changes outside of the linux subsystem. I was using Atom to make edits and not seeing rebuilds. However, if I touched files from bash or edited them via vi I'd see a re-build and reload. I didn't get too far in making webpack notice file change from Atom but if I set CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true in my environment the changes would eventually get noticed after some short polling interval.